# Register IAuthenticationManager with Simple Injector

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2, simple-injector

I am having a configuration setup for Simple Injector where I have moved all of my registrations to OWIN pipeline.

Now the problem is I have a controller `AccountController` which actually takes parameters as

```
public AccountController(
    AngularAppUserManager userManager, 
    AngularAppSignInManager signinManager, 
    IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
{
    this._userManager = userManager;
    this._signInManager = signinManager;
    this._authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
}
```

Now my Owin Pipeline configurations looks something like this

```
public void Configure(IAppBuilder app)
{
    _container = new Container();
    ConfigureOwinSecurity(app);
    ConfigureWebApi(app);
    ConfigureSimpleinjector(_container);

    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        _container.Register<IOwinContext>(() => context);
        await next();
    });

    _container.Register<IAuthenticationManager>(
        () => _container.GetInstance<IOwinContext>().Authentication);

    _container.Register<SignInManager<Users, Guid>, AngularAppSignInManager>();
}

private static void ConfigureOwinSecurity(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        CookieName = "AppNgCookie",
        //LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
    });
}

private static void ConfigureWebApi(IAppBuilder app)
{
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
    WebApiConfig.Register(config);
    app.UseWebApi(config);
}

private static void ConfigureSimpleinjector(Container container)
{
    SimpleInjectorInitializer.Initialize(container);
}
```

And Simple Injector Initializer looks something like this

```
private static void InitializeContainer(Container container)
{
    container.Register<DbContext, AngularAppContext>();

    container.Register<IUserStore<Users, Guid>, AngularAppUserStore>();
    container.Register<IRoleStore<Roles, Guid>, AngularAppRoleStore>();

    container.Register<UserManager<Users, Guid>, AngularAppUserManager>();
    container.Register<RoleManager<Roles, Guid>, AngularAppRoleManager>();
    //container.RegisterPerWebRequest<SignInManager<Users, Guid>, AngularAppSignInManager>();

    container.Register<IdentityFactoryOptions<AngularAppUserManager>, IdentityFactoryOptions<AngularAppUserManager>>();
    //container.Register<IAuthenticationManager>(() => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication);

    //container.Register<SignInManager<Users, Guid>, AngularAppSignInManager>();
    // For instance:
    // container.Register<IUserRepository, SqlUserRepository>();
}
```

Now the problem is The controller is not able to register `IAuthenticationManager`. I tried using

```
container.Register<IAuthenticationManager>(
    () => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication);
```

But that Leaves me with Exception as:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No owin.Environment item was found
>   in the context.

In this line

```
container.Register<IAuthenticationManager>(
    () => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication);
```

I also tried instead of using `HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication` with the configuration mentioned above in `public void Configure(app)` method to register using `app.Use()`. And then later resolve it via container to get the `IAuthenticationManager`. But every possibilities have left me failed.

What am I missing here? Why  `HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentcation`  is failing to resolve authentcation from OwinContext?

And if thats not, why is the same configuration via `app.Use` also not working?

Comment: I completely agree with Ric's answer. IMO it should be marked as answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are doing with `IAuthenticationManager` registration [worked for me](https://github.com/trailmax/ClaimsAuthorisation/blob/master/ClaimsAuth/App_Start/SimpleInjector.cs) with no issues. At some point I was getting the same exception as you were getting, but that was caused by line with

```
container.Verify();
```

just after the container configuration. It was trying to create all instances of registered objects, but there was no `HttpContext.Current` present, hence the exception.

Are you not getting any instances out of container before any HTTP request is available? If you really need them, then the only way to work around this is use Factory, as suggested by NightOwl888. If you don't need container before the HTTP request, then refactor, so it is not use outwith HTTP request.

Comment: This actually is the one which caused the issue . I wonder if there are any ways that I can exclude a specific registration out of verify() method or so ?

Comment: No, don't think you can do exclusion. But `Verify()` is not mandatory and for testing purposes. Is that right, @Steven?

Comment: It seems like this issue previously had come https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/discussions/461871

Comment: Today I faced another problem due to this . I removed the `container.verify()` but that caused me to break all of my tests where the object graph was supposed to be used for others . Cause I was calling `SimpleInjectorInitializer.Initialize()` to create registrations . But seems without calling verify it actually doesn't registering . Cause I am not able to resolve my commandHandlers now .

Comment: A DI container [cannot *really* verify its configuration against your application](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/12/21/TestingContainerConfigurations/) at application startup, it can only verify that the configuration is internally consistent. The DI container will (appropriately) throw an exception in the case where a dependency isn't properly registered anyway. Therefore, the Simple Injector `Verify()` method is practically useless. Interestingly, it does sometimes reject a configuration that an application *can* run with.

Comment: To support point of @NightOwl888, read this blog post from Mark Seemann http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/12/21/TestingContainerConfigurations/

Answer (score 28):

As TrailMax already mentioned, the exception you got probably got raised during the call to `container.Verify()`. At application start-up time there is no `HttpContext`, hence the exception.

Although the removal of the call to `container.Verify()` will 'solve' the problem, I would advise against doing this and I will suggest a better solution below.

NightOwl888 references an old article of Mark Seemann (which I highly respect for his work on DI). In [that article](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/12/21/TestingContainerConfigurations/) Mark explains why he thinks that verifying the container is useless. This article however seems outdated, and conflicts with newer articles from Mark. In [a newer article](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/11/06/WhentouseaDIContainer/) Mark explains that one of the big advantages of using [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/) (that is Dependency Injection without using a DI container) is that [it provides the fastest feedback about correctness that you can get](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/04/29/Feedbackmechanismsandtradeoffs/). Mark, and the rest of us, obviously values both the compiler's feedback and the feedback from static code analysis tools, as rapid feedback mechanism. Both Simple Injector's `.Verify()` and the [Diagnostic Services](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/diagnostics.html) attempt to bring this fast feedback back. In my view, Simple Injector's `.Verify()` method takes on the job that the compiler would do for you when doing Pure DI and the Diagnostic Services is in a sense static code analysis tool specialized to your DI configuration.

While it is indeed not possible for a container to do a 100% verification of its configuration, verifying still proved a valuable practice to me. It would be silly to think that a simple call to `.Verify()` would result in a completely bug free or even a working application. If somebody may think that this is what ‘verifying’ your DI configuration means, I understand why they would argue that this functionality is worthless. Sounds like a statement of truism. There is no container out there, including Simple Injector, which pretends having such a feature.

You are off course still responsible for writing integration and/or unit tests for e.g. detecting if the order of applied decorators is correct or if all implementations of `ISomeService<T>` are indeed registered in the container.

I want to mention 2 specific arguments from Mark’s blog against verifying the container.

> It is easy to get into the situation that the container verifies, but still breaks at runtime.

I agree with that, but I do think that the Simple Injector documentation has got some great guidance on how to approach this [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/2.7/howto.html#verify-configuration).

> When doing convention over configuration it's easy to get registrations that shouldn't be in the container anyway.

I never had this problem, because I think it is a sane practice to prevent getting in this situation anyway.

**Back to the question:**

Although one of the tips in the Simple Injector documentation is to use abstract factories, I wouldn't do that in this case. Creating a factory for something that already exists, sounds pretty weird to me. Maybe it is just a problem of correct naming, but why would an AccountController need a `AuthenticationFactory` or `AuthenticationContext`? In other words, why should the application know anything about us having problem wiring things up because of some design quirks in ASP.NET Identity?

Instead, by adjusting the registration for the `IAuthenticationManager` we can return an Authentication component from a newly created OwinContext at startup/verify time and return the 'normal' or configured `AuthenticationManager` at runtime. This will remove the need for a factory and moves the responsibility to the Composition Root where it should be. And lets you inject the `IAuthenticationManager` everywhere you need it, while still being able to make a call to `.Verify()`.

The code looks like:

```
container.RegisterPerWebRequest<IAuthenticationManager>(() => 
    AdvancedExtensions.IsVerifying(container) 
        ? new OwinContext(new Dictionary<string, object>()).Authentication 
        : HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication);
```

An even more SOLID solution however would be to not depend on the `IAuthenticationManager` at all, because depending on this interface causes us to violate the Interface Segregation Principle, making it hard to create a proxy implementation for it that delays the creation.

You could do this by defining an abstraction which fits your needs and only your needs. Looking at the identity template calls to the `IAuthenticationManager` this abstraction would need nothing more than the `.SignIn()` and `.SignOut()` methods. This however would force you to completely refactor the crappy `AccountController` that you got 'for free' by the Visual Studio template, which can be quite an undertaking.

Comment: This is the best answer!

Comment: "refactor the crappy `AccountController` that you got 'for free' by the Visual Studio template", <= this quote. made my day.

Comment: This definitely needs to be the accepted solution. Refactoring that authentication controller leads to positive changes all down the pipeline, such as fixing the AppUserManager registrations with both SI and OWIN. So messy before and so clean after

Comment: May I ask for an example on how `AccountController` should look or the controller provided by @NightOwl888 is the best option?

Comment: @leandro_soares take a look here for a complete mvc 5 identity setup with simpleinjector: http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/discussions/564822

Comment: The issue mentioned by @Ric.Net has moved here:  https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/597

Answer (score 4):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27052029/null-user-on-httpcontext-obtained-from-structuremap/27075242#27075242).

Although you are accessing a different type, the problem is the same. You cannot rely on properties of HttpContext during application startup because the application is initialized outside of the user's context. The solution is to make an abstract factory to read the values at runtime rather than at object creation and inject the factory rather than the IAuthenticationManager type into your controller.

```
public class AccountController
{
    private readonly AngularAppUserManager _userManager;
    private readonly AngularAppSignInManager _signInManager;
    private readonly IAuthenticationManagerFactory _authenticationManagerFactory;

    public AccountController(AngularAppUserManager userManager
      , AngularAppSignInManager signinManager
      , IAuthenticationManagerFactory authenticationManagerFactory)
    {
        this._userManager = userManager;
        this._signInManager = signinManager;
        this._authenticationManagerFactory = authenticationManagerFactory;
    }

    private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
    {
        get { return this._authenticationManagerFactory.Create(); }
    }

    private void DoSomething()
    {
        // Now it is safe to call into HTTP context
        var manager = this.AuthenticationManger;
    }
}

public interface IAuthenticationMangerFactory
{
    IAuthenticationManger Create();
}

public class AuthenticationMangerFactory
{
    public IAuthenticationManger Create()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
    }
}

// And register your factory...
container.Register<IAuthenticationManagerFactory, AuthenticationMangerFactory>();
```

Comment: The idea seems to be valid . But is there not any other way ? I mean microsoft wouldn't have made so big blunder I suppose that they would tightly couple authenticationmanager to system.web ?

Comment: Many people make the mistake of thinking that the DI container is some magic bullet that is supposed to create every instance. But not every object can be created at application startup, which is the only time that composing the application is relevant. Sometimes we need to be able to get instances at runtime, and that is when we turn to abstract factory to solve the problem (which is preferable to [service locator](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/)).

Comment: @NightOwl888 just one thing, is it correct to create a GenericFactory with one `T Create<T>()` which calls the container to do `container.GetInstance<T>()`?

Comment: There are [cases where you need to provide a way to inject and later release instances](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-framework/) (in case a later implementation will have disposable components in it) in order to create an integration point for others.  But those pieces should be considered part of the *composition root*, not part of the application as a whole. Just creating a wrapper around the container still abuses it as a "super factory" that can resolve any type. The argument against service locator is that types not explicitly known, and this has the exact same issue.