# Registering IUserStore with Simple Injector 3.1.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, asp.net-identity, simple-injector

Hi I have been trying to register the default IUserStore that is in the premade Identity class ApplicationUserManager with SimpleInjector

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser, int>
    {
        public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser, int> store)
            : base(store)
        {
        }
```

I have a SimpleInjectorInitializer file in the App_Start folder that looks like this:

```
public static class SimpleInjectorInitializer
{
    public static void RegisterDependencies(Container container)
    {
        container.Register<ICatalogRepository, CatalogRepository>();
        container.Register<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();

        container.Register<ICatalogService, CatalogService>();
        container.Register<IUserService, UserService>();
        container.Register<IAdminService, AdminService>();

        container.Register<AccountController>();
        container.Register<ApplicationUserManager>();
        //container.Register<CustomUserStore>();
        //container.RegisterCollection(typeof(IUserStore<>), new[] { typeof(ApplicationUser) });

        //container.Register<IUserStore<>, store>();

        //container.RegisterPerWebRequest<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>(() => new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(container.GetInstance<ApplicationDbContext>()));

        container.Verify();
    }
}
```

As you can see I have tried a few times to get it working by looking at similar Stack Overflow questions but it has either not changed the outcome or given a syntax error.

Currently when clicking the sign in button on the application homepage, this error is thrown:

> The constructor of type ApplicationUserManager contains the parameter
>   with name 'store' and type IUserStore that is
>   not registered. Please ensure IUserStore is
>   registered, or change the constructor of ApplicationUserManager.

If the two lines below register ApplicationUserManager are uncommented then this error is thrown:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   SimpleInjector.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The supplied type ApplicationUser does not
>   implement IUserStore.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Please check this link, it has solution very well explained. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30602687/simple-injector-identity-usermanagerappuser-int32-registration-error

Comment: I have tried to use the examples from the link posted already and they seem to either apply to a different version of Simple Injector or they dont work with my solution.

Answer (score 3):

I answered my own question. I used various other stack overflow questions and the answer was to edit my SimpleInjectorInitializer as follows:

```
public static class SimpleInjectorInitializer
{
    public static void RegisterDependencies(Container container)
    {
        container.Register<ICatalogRepository, CatalogRepository>();
        container.Register<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();

        container.Register<ICatalogService, CatalogService>();
        container.Register<IUserService, UserService>();
        container.Register<IAdminService, AdminService>();

        container.RegisterPerWebRequest<IUserStore<ApplicationUser, int>>(
            () => new CustomUserStore(container.GetInstance<ApplicationDbContext>()));
        container.RegisterPerWebRequest(
            () => new UserManager<ApplicationUser, int>(
                new CustomUserStore(
                    container.GetInstance<ApplicationDbContext>())));
        container.Register(
            () => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication);
    }
}
```

Note: `container.Verify()` will prevent this solution from working but it does work. I need to do further research to find a better way of doing this whilst using `container.Verify()`.

Comment: Don't forget to register `ApplicationDbContext` explicitly in the container and don't forget to call Verify().

Comment: "container.Verify() will prevent this solution from working but it does work". Calling `Verify` will fail, because the solution is flawed. Verify fails, because `ApplicationDbContext` is a transient, which isn't disposed. Try registering `ApplicationDbContext` as scoped (web request) intance instead.