# Ninject always injects null HttpContext.Current()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject

I am attempting to inject a UserFactory via Ninject, here is my binding:

```
  var u = new CurrentUserProvider(HttpContext.Current);
            kernel.Bind<ICurrentUserProvider>().ToMethod(context => u).InRequestScope();
```

This factory uses `HttpContext` to read a authentication cookie and populate a `CurrentUser` object, HttpContext is passed as a constructor parameter:

```
 public class CurrentUserProvider : ICurrentUserProvider
{
    public ICurrentUser CurrentUser { get; set; }

    public CurrentUserProvider(HttpContext context)
    {
        CurrentUser = GetCurrentUser(context);
    }

    private static ICurrentUser GetCurrentUser(HttpContext ctx)
    {
        var httpCookie = ctx.Request.Cookies[".ASPXAUTH"];

        if (httpCookie != null)
        {
            var cookie = httpCookie.Value;
            var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie);

            if (ticket != null)
            {
                var x = ticket.UserData.FromJson<CurrentUser>();
                ctx.Session["UserID"] = x.DatabaseName;
                return x;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

However the HttpContext that gets passed into the UserFactory constructor is always null. This is a MVC4 project if that makes any difference to the approach.

Update:
I have also tried the following code which does not error but my injected `CurrentUserProvider` property remains null:

```
 kernel.Bind<ICurrentUserProvider>().To<CurrentUserProvider>().InRequestScope()
            .WithConstructorArgument("context", ninjectContext => HttpContext.Current);
```

Comment: Well, first of all, you really shouldn't be re-decrypting the auth cookie like that, nor should you be using session to store the UserID information.  You should instead be using a custom IPrincipal, such as defined here: http://peterbromberg.net/post/Implementing-a-Custom-IPrincipal-in-an-ASPNET-MVC-Application.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, I'll look into that. In this case I am not using membership but a bespoke authentication which writes a custom auth cookie. The cookie only stores non-sensitive data.

Comment: What does membership have to do with anything?  IPrincipal is FormsAuthentication related, not Membership related.  The example uses membership but you can use whatever you want instead.

Comment: Also, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27052029/null-user-on-httpcontext-obtained-from-structuremap/27075242#27075242

Comment: Thanks @NightOwl888, your answers got me re-thinking my approach and I've now got it all working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to NightOwl888 for pointing me in the right direction with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28255026/20048).

Instead of trying to work with HttpContext directly with Ninject, instead I have injected a factory object along these lines:

```
  public class AspNetUserContext : IUserContext
{
    public User CurrentUser
    {
        // Do not inject HttpContext in the ctor, but use it
        // here in this property
        get { return new User(HttpContext.Current.User); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are creating the `CurrentUserProvider` object too early.  If you want it created at the time of binding, I believe you can update your code to be something like this:

```
    kernel.Bind<ICurrentUserProvider>().ToMethod(context => new CurrentUserProvider(context)).InRequestScope();
```

Comment: Thanks, but my injected property is always null.